# How do I get "paste" command to fill columns first before it fills the rows? Basically columnating the STDOUT

Tags: bash, pagination, multiple-columns, paste

I need to simply columnate my studout into two columns with paste, but so far it's taking each line and filling out the row before the column.

Try this:

```
]$ echo test1$'\n'test2$'\n'test3$'\n'test4$'\n' | paste - -
test1   test2
test3   test4
```

Expected result:

```
test1   test3
test2   test4
```

I'd use pr, but pr seems to cut off things text prematurely, and overall is really cumbersome and complicated to use with a bunch of frivilous options that don't make sense)

Answer (score 3):

`pr` does the job

```
$ echo -e "test1\ntest2\ntest3\ntest4" | pr -2ts

test1   test3
test2   test4
```

removed tab since it's the default as per Sundeep's comment.

Comment: since tab is default delimiter, one can also use `echo -e "test1\ntest2\ntest3\ntest4" | pr -2ts`